# Mylyn doesn't filter the resources in the Navigator- or Package Explorer views

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I am using Eclipse 3.7 with Mylyn and would like to use it to focus only on the files that are in the current context.

When I activate a task with no context, the Navigator and Package Explorer views should both be empty, allowing me to add files to the context. If I add some files to a bugs context, save the context, restart eclipse and activate the same bug, what I expect is that only the resources in the context will be visible, but what happens is that both views just shows all resources as they would without any active tasks.

Another thing is that normally there is a small Mylyn pane with options to toggle focus on the current context inside each of the two views, but in my installation, they are both missing. Could this be a consequence of running Unity on Ubuntu? (It is known to do odd things with scroll bars.)

It looks like a bug - any suggestions?

Comment: I have installed the stock version that came with ubuntu 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never install Eclipse from a Linux package repository; always download it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads and make sure you have the Oracle JDK installed and configure Eclipse to use it as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

I suspect the Ubuntu package of Eclipse is either bastardized or just plain broken, so getting it from the right source should get you going.

Comment: Thats a surprising angle - I've rarely had any problems with packages from Ubuntu, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: I have just installed straight from eclipse.org and added MyLyn on top. It works like it should.

Comment: I'm not a linux user, so I can't comment about the general quality of provided packages. But I have been very active in Eclipse community support for many years and any vendor-provided packages of Eclipse have long been a source of headaches. I don't know what they do to Eclipse other than try to make it use gcj, but it's a common problem.